# HLOOKUP in powerquery

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I know we can do VLOOKUPS in PQ.

However, how do we do HLOOKUPS in PQ?

I have searched the internet few times in past one week but unable to find some answer for it.

Comment: Could you provide more details? This feels like an XY problem...

Comment: Sure...we can do InnerJoins/OuterJoins in PQ and get the joins...it is similar to VLOOKUP in excel..but I don't understand how to merge tables just on basis of Row name (HLOOKUP in excel)

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of what you are trying to do? You might be able to pivot your table and use a `VLOOKUP` type of logic.

Comment: What do you _mean_ by Row name?

Comment: Hi NetMage, apologies...I meant column name (header)...

Comment: Alex, I will soon add some data to show what I mean...thanks for the reply :)